# Ionic Crosswalk Apache Cordova vulnerability Issue on Playstore

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We are using Ionic 1.3.21 and crosswalk 13.41.318.0. 
For building the app I add the android@5.0.0 platform.
But when I add crosswalk to my project it replaces my android platform with android 4.0.0-dev. Now google is giving me the following warning.
"Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Please migrate your app(s) to Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK"
My Cordova CLI version is 6.2.0. I am not sure as to what I need to update to satisfy Google's requirement. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You have to update your crosswalk-plugin. It is now at version 18, which should also allow you to target newer android sdk's. It is important to keep your plugins more-or-less up-to-date to deal with security issues.

Comment: Thanks bro. But when I see the crosswalk plugin for Ionic, I cannot see a version higher than 13.41.318.0 even on their website.

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html

Comment: Try to install directly from crosswalk (see [GitHub](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview)).

Comment: No resolution yet on this. I still keep seeing the warning in my Google Play Application Console